# How to handle "many columns" in OLAP RDBMS

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, olap, star-schema

I have a fact that has around 1K different numerical attributes (i.e. columns). I would like to store this in to a column-oriented DB and perform cube analysis on it.

I tried to design a star schema, but I'm not sure how to handle this many columns. Normalising it sounds wrong, but I can't just have flat columns either. The combination of attributes are also too diverse to have a simple dimension table for this, even if I'd reduce the numerical values into categories (ranges), which is an option. I thought about storing them as XML or JSON for each row, but that doesn't sound great either.

If it helps, I'm planning to use Amazon's redshift for the DB.

Note: We have strong preference for RedShift as it fits perfectly for at least other few operations we do on this data. Hence I want to avoid other technologies like HBase if possible.

Comment: what is the problem of having 1K attribute columns ? sounds like star is the solution for you. if you split or denormelize you'l have to deal with other problems like missing values for example.

Comment: mind if we ask what you're storing?

Comment: @haki: wondered if having a very wide table is a bad idea, perhaps in terms of performance (and table width limitation)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: A wide range of probabilities. The raw data is decimal but it would be acceptable to turn them in to categories by range (e.g. 0.0 - 0.1, 0.1 - 0.2, etc.)

Comment: text mining app?

Comment: It's the result of mining texts, yes @NeilMcGuigan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding why you would want to do this, imagine you want to see which words/short phrases in customer emails are associated with costly repairs, and you want to be able to analyze this using OLAP. It can be costly to tokenize/grammify many documents, so you might want to store the tokens/grams in a form which your OLAP server understands, ie columns.

Consider MonetDB, which allows for a [practically unlimited](http://www.monetdb.org/Home/Features) number of columns.

Redshift maxes out at [1600 columns](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=437136).

Another option would be to use [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and only choose the top 1600 components, but that can make interpretation difficut.

Another option would be to use Postgres and store the tokenized strings or n-grams in a string array field, but your OLAP server would need to support that.

Comment: Out of curiosity what could possibly be gained from having 1600 Columns in one table??????????

Comment: @Zane, In text mining, you create one column for each unique word in your corpus. This is called a word vector. This could be 10,000 to 50,000 words. Instead of re-creating the word vector every time, you might want to store it in the database. I would probably serialize it and store it in a blob, but some might want it in a regular tabular form.

Comment: Or you could store them in rows and pivot at runtime (perhaps outside). Or maybe not use an RDBMS at all.

Comment: Rows. THe problem with the text vector as you give it is that th table is not stable. Add a text and you may get new fields. That is always VERY problematic.